# Font name appearing in index (left pane) of pdf

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec

What is the reason that the font name is appearing in the index (left pane) of the pdf file. The MWE is provided:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Adds the bookmark for only the first slide if it is using \pause or something like that
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\eps}{{\setsansfont{Calibri} {ϵ}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hello-\eps}
  Hello World
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same code does not produce any font name in my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `\setsansfont{}` mid-document. It is intended to be used just once at the beginning of the document. If you want to use a font many times in a document you should define a new font family.

```
\newfontfamily{\calibri}{Calibri}
\newcommand{\eps}{{\calibri ϵ}}
```

The reason why the font name is appearing in the bookmarks can be found inside the log file. You should always look for clues inside the log file if something is going wrong.

```
 Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
 (hyperref)                removing `\setsansfont' on input line 20.
```

So hyperref removes the `setsansfont`-macro but the following argument hence the font name will be kept.

[image: bookmark]